# How to get access token with tumblr oauth

Tags: python, oauth, tumblr

I'm completely new to oauth, and I'm trying to get a list of blogs the user is following.

The authorize link this produces links me to a page that prompts the user to either deny or allow access (If I manually paste the link into my browser.). It redirects to a url ending in oauth_verifier=xxxx. I copy that into the command line.

However, I get an error 400 raised on line 95.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
 69     import oauth2 as oauth
 70     import urlparse
 71 
 72     url = "http://www.tumblr.com/oauth"
 73     request_token_url = '%s/request_token' % url
 74     authorize_url = '%s/authorize/' % url
 75     access_token_url = '%s/access_token/' % url
 76 
 77     consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=oauth_key,secret=oauth_secret)
 78     client = oauth.Client(consumer)
 79     response, content = client.request(request_token_url, 'GET')
 80     if response['status'] != '200':
 81         raise Exception('Invalid response: %s' % response['status'])
 82 
 83     request_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))
 84     authorize_link = '%s?oauth_token=%s' % 
 85     print "Go to: " , authorize_link,"\n"
 86     oauth_verifier = raw_input("What is the oauth_verifier?")
 87 
 88     token = oauth.Token(request_token['oauth_token'], request_token['oauth_token_secret'])
 89     token.set_verifier(oauth_verifier)
 90     client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)
 91 
 92     print "token: ",token,"\n"
 93     response, content = client.request(access_token_url, "POST")
 94 
 95     if response['status']!='200':
 96         raise Exception('Invalid response %s' %response['status'])
 97
```

(authorize_url,request_token['oauth_token'])

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to figure out OAuth in Python and move on getting your list of blogs is by using [Temboo's](http://temboo.com) OAuth wrappers.

Temboo simplifies the OAuth process for Tumblr by breaking it down into two calls:

`InitializeOAuth` - returns a Tumblr authorization URL that you can show to your users and have them grant your application access to their Tumblr account.

`FinalizeOAuth` - returns the access tokens your app needs for authenticated access to Tumblr accounts.

You can experiment with Temboo's Tumblr OAuth support in your browser from the link below, and then generate the source code you need to use this behavior in your app with the Temboo Python SDK.

https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Tumblr/OAuth/

You can see an example of how Temboo handles OAuth for Facebook [here](http://temboo.com/examples).

Temboo can also help you get the list of blogs that a Tumblr user is following - see [here](https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Tumblr/User/RetrieveFollowedBlogsForUser/).

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo, so let me know if you have any questions!)